# Laravel Create and Download Zipped File

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm having trouble on Creating and downloading Zip file

I see on this code on
http://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-create-zip-file-in-laravel-using-ziparchive

This is my controller

```
public function download(){
    $FOLDERID = $_GET['id'];
    $FILEPATH = *My Database Query*
    $PATHTOFILE = public_path().'/images/';
    $ZIPNAME = 'ZIPFILENAME.zip';
    $ZIP = new ZipArchive;
    if ($ZIP->open($PATHTOFILE.'/'.$ZIPNAME, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        $FILES = *My Database Query to get file*
            foreach ($FILES as $FILE) {
              $ZIP->addFile($FILE->File_Path , $FILE->File_Name);
            }
        $ZIP->close();
    }
    else{
        return "NO FILES CREATED";
    }
```

and I dont know what this one do

```
    $HEADERS = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        );
```

And this one is for download the zip

```
    if(file_exists($PATHTOFILE)){

    return Response()->download($PATHTOFILE, $ZIPNAME, $HEADERS);

    }else{

        return "asd";

    }
```

still didnt know what #HEADERS do

Im having trouble on Creating Zip File, The error always on the $ZIP->close();

It says

ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Bad file descriptor

can you guys help me which one i did wrong?

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: what is the error

Comment: ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Bad file descriptor
sorry i didnt attach it

Comment: check the same name file is located on the folder where you create the file. Actually you have to upload other folder instead.

Comment: No file created

Comment: please check this link, it is very easy to make zip file by it.https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-55-create-zip-archive-file-and-download-example

Answer (score 0):

create route

```
Route::get('download-zip', 'ZipController@downloadZip');
```

step:2 Create Controller
add one new method for route. downloadZip() will generate new zip file and download as response, so let's add below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use File;
use ZipArchive;

class ZipController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function downloadZip()
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $fileName = 'myNewFile.zip';

        if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
        {
            $files = File::files(public_path('myFiles'));

            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
                $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }

            $zip->close();
        }

        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
}
```